# Solving equations in R similar to the Excel solver parameters function

Tags: r, excel, function, solver

I have a question concerning the possibility to solve functions in R, and doing the same using excel.

However I want to do it with R to show that R is better for my colleagues :)

Here is the equation:

```
f0<-1e-9
t_pw<-30e-9
a<-30.7397582453682
c<-6.60935546184612

P<-1-exp((-t_pw)*f0*exp(-a*(1-b/c)^2))
```

I want to find the `b` value for `P<-0.5`. In Excel we can do it by selecting P value column and setting it to 0.5 and then by using the solver parameters function.

I don't know which method is the best? Or any other way to do it?

Thankx.

Comment: See packages `BB`   and `ktsolve` for two examples.  Or `stats:optim`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: With your package I get "Unsuccessful convergence" and several warnings: "Function returns a scalar. Function BBoptim or spg is better." Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: @vonjd  Well, how about follwing the warnings and trying those other functions?  Your data are probably near-singular or excessively noisy, and it may take some trials to get an answer (let alone a *valid* answer)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Thank you for the quick response. I tried the above example with your package but it may be ill defined. So BB and ktsolve cannot be used as you suggested in the comment?

Comment: If the solution provided by @Ben is correct, you should edit your question to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a strong suspicion that your equation was supposed to include `-t_pw/f0`, not `-t_pw*f0`, and that `t_pw` was supposed to be `3.0e-9`, not `30e-9`.

```
 Pfun <- function(b,f0=1e-9,t_pw=3.0e-9,
                  a=30.7397582453682,
                  c=6.60935546184612) {
               1-exp((-t_pw)/f0*exp(-a*(1-b/c)^2))
           }
```

Then @Lyzander's `uniroot()` suggestion works fine:

```
 u1 <- uniroot(function(x) Pfun(x)-0.5,c(6,10))
```

The estimated value here is 8.05.

```
 par(las=1,bty="l")
 curve(Pfun,from=0,to=10,xname="b")
 abline(h=0.5,lty=2)
 abline(v=u1$root,lty=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to solve an equation the simplest thing is to do is to use `uniroot` which is in base-R.

```
f0<-1e-9
t_pw<-30e-9
a<-30.7397582453682
c<-6.60935546184612

func <- function(b) {
    1-exp((-t_pw)*f0*exp(-a*(1-b/c)^2)) - 0.5
}

#interval is the range of values of b to look for a solution
#it can be -Inf, Inf
> uniroot(func, interval=c(-1000, 1000), extendInt='yes')
Error in uniroot(func, interval = c(-1000, 1000), extendInt = "yes") : 
  no sign change found in 1000 iterations
```

As you see above my `unitroot` function fails. This is because there is no single solution to your equation which is easy to see as well. `exp(-0.0000000000030 * <positive number between 0-1>)` is practically  (very close to) 1 so your equation becomes `1 - 1 - 0.5 = 0` which doesn't hold. You can see the same with a plot as well:

```
curve(func) #same result for curve(func, from=-1000, to=1000)
```

[image]

In this function the result will be -0.5 for any b.

So one way to do it fast, is `uniroot` but probably for a different equation.

And a working example:

```
myfunc2 <- function(x) x - 2 

> uniroot(myfunc2, interval=c(0,10))
$root
[1] 2

$f.root
[1] 0

$iter
[1] 1

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 8
```

Comment: yes but I can get the solution for `b` with excel_?

Comment: Only if you optimise. Solver in excel optimises i.e. finds what value of b minimises or maximises the function. This is totally different to solving an equation. If you want to minimise/maximise then use `optim` as:  `optim(1, func, method='Brent', upper=100, lower=1)`. Optim by default minimises, change the sign of the equation to maximise. Your function in this case is yielding the same result for any b which means that the solution will always be the upper limit. In optim's output `$par` is the value of b that minimises the function.

Comment: yes that one I was looking for `optim` function. On the other hand `b` value should be `8.5` but `optim(1, func, method='Brent', upper=100, lower=1)` gives upper value `100?

Comment: Your function returns the same value `-0.5` for any value of `b`. Therefore, there is no value that minimises your function. Therefore, optim returns the upper limit as the `best` solution only because it tries values starting from the lower to the upper limit. It stops when it checks b=100 and since it sees no improvement in finding a minimum it returns that as the `optimum` value. I don't know why excel would give a result of 8.5 but it makes me think you copied the function in your question wrong. If not maybe excel iterates the values of b in a different way.

Comment: thank you for explonation. I checked the function and its exactly same. Maybe yes excel doing it in other way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Really glad I could be of help :)